# Apache CXF Jax-RS bean validation: NoClassDefFoundError javax.validation.ValidationException not found by org.apache.cxf.cxf-core

Tags: java, apache, jax-rs, cxf

I am trying to get Bean validation working, but it is not working out. I am using Apache CXF with JAX-RS in Apache Karaf. I have 1 bundle where I want to enable the bean validation inside the Blueprint.XML file. However, when I try to enable the Bean validation with the provider it gives me an error that the ValidationException could not be found by cxf core dependency.

```
btw cxf version is 3.1.5

Blueprint.xml:
    <jaxrs:server address="/person" id="personService">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="personServiceImpl" /><!--Verwijst naar line boven--> 
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging />

            <!--<ref bean="commonValidationFeature" />-->

                <!--<bean id="validationProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider" />-->
            <!--<bean id="validationProviderResolver" class="mycompany.myproject.core.utils.HibernateValidationProviderResolver"/>-->   


        </jaxrs:features>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
                <property name="dropRootElement" value="true" />
                <property name="ignoreNamespaces" value="true" />
                <property name="convention" value="mapped"/>
                <property name="unmarshallAsJaxbElement" value="true" />
                <property name="dropCollectionWrapperElement" value="true"/>
                <property name="serializeAsArray" value="true"/>
                <property name="supportUnwrapped" value="true"/>                
                <property name="readXsiType" value="false" />
            </bean>        

            <bean class="mycompany.myproject.core.utils.MyExceptionMapper" />
            <bean class="mycompany.myproject.core.utils.CustomValidationException" />
                        <bean id="validationProviderResolver" class="mycompany.myproject.core.utils.HibernateValidationProviderResolver"/>  
                <bean id="validationProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider" />

            <!--    <bean id="exceptionMapper" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper"/>-->

        </jaxrs:providers>

    </jaxrs:server>

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mycompany.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>company-core</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <description>1 install -s mvn:org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.4
        2 install -s mvn:mycompany.myproject/company-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT</description>
    <groupId>mycompany.myproject</groupId>
    <name>company-core</name>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mycompany.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--parent pom-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <!--hibernate shit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <!-- use 3.0-b02 version for Java 6 -->
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        DEP remove kan-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--GSON DEPENDENCY-->


        <dependency>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Error message
https://i.stack.imgur.com/69mYu.png

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version? Latest release is 3.2.4

Comment: I am going to try to install it with the latest version, I'll be back

Comment: Hey, I managed to get it working by upgrading to 3.2.4 and importing missing bundles by reading the headers of the bundles. Also, I followed the following tutorial: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_cxf_development_guide/validation